# Erro ao instalar o mongodb 3.0 no linux Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mongodb

Estou tentando instalar o `MongoDB` no `Ubuntu 15.10`, mas, não consigo instalar o mongo sempre retornando o seguinte erro ao iniciar o serviço.

> Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Sei que as versões do Mongo não são instaladas nas versões que não são `LTS` do Ubuntu. Mas existe um jeito de bular isso?

Comment: Experimenta `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb`

Comment: Quais foram seus passos para essa instalação não ter êxito?

Comment: ainda lançara o um LTS  na versão 5.0 desse ano 2021. Talvez seja o tal conflito mencionado na pagina. o pacote mongodb oferecido pelo debian não tem vinculo com MongoDB. Desistala  mongodb e importe a chave pública e especifica o mirror no list  tentou desta forma ?

Answer (score -2):

1. Instale-o com o comando:
   **sudo apt-get install mongodb-server**
2. Após concluida a instalação, tente iniciar o servidor com o comando:
   **sudo mongod**

   Provavelmente ele apresentará a mensagem de erro abaixo: ERROR:

> ```
> dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
> ```

```
Isso significa que o diretório em questão não existe, então crie-o
com o comando:

**sudo mkdir -p /data/db**
```

3. Após isso, execute novamente o comando "sudo mongod" e o servidor
   estará online. Para confirmar, apenas execute o comando "**ps aux
   |grep mongo**" e caso tenha um resultado semelhante ao apresentado
   abaixo é sinal de que seu servidor está pronto para uso:

> mongodb   2648  0.6  8.8 389356 44140 ?        Ssl  09:05   0:01
>       /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

Comment: Não funcionou, faltou atenção ao fato que não é uma simples instalação do `mongodb`.